# How to post a new thread and new comments to a current thread in iOS to Salesforce's Chatter feed

Tags: api, new-operator, comments, salesforce-chatter

Basically I am trying accomplish 2 goals:
(1) Start a new Chatter Thread, and
(2) Comment on an existing Chatter Thread that has been loaded.

I am using OAuth to get connected and am able to successfully view and update custom objects but can't seem to figure out how to access and create a new chatter thread using the same [switchboard create:] method.

Does anyone have any idea where to start? I have tried their documentation and the best I could find was Asynchronous HTTPS posts with a body and a parent ID but how can I accomplish the same thing using the provided switchboard interface in the iOS client?

Any help appreciated,
Thanks,
~Arash

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the [Salesforce Mobile SDK for iOS](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS) on GitHub. There's a great FAQ and examples to access Chatter.

You can use the [SFRestAPI](http://forcedotcom.github.com/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/Documentation/SalesforceSDK/Classes/SFRestAPI.html) to access Chatter objects. See the [Chatter REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/index.htm) documentation for queries and relationships between Chatter objects.